# Parse error: Certificate must be a .p12 file (got application/pkcs-12)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to upload a .p12 file in Parse for Push Notifications and I have been getting this error: Certificate must be a .p12 file (got application/pkcs-12).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. This problem happens just in FireFox, when I tried to upload the same file using Safari, everything went well.